# Multiple foreign keys on one table pointing to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a risk table, and in it i have 3 foreign keys pointing to one table, and 3 foreign keys pointing to another. Is this okay?

Comment: Hi Chris Dunphy, can you please provide more details (the models and table structure)?

Comment: Yes, this question needs more context